# R: extract the first part of string, separated by a specific character

Tags: r

I have column having values like "xxxxTxxx" or "xxTxx", always separated by 'T', I i want to extract the first part of the string, that is prior to 'T', AND, saved it in another column.

a <- c("abcT123","Dsds1Tdf4")

i get to get a table with 3 columns as below:

a                 b          c
abcT123           abc        123
Dsds1Tdf4         Dsds       Tdf4

Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
cbind(a,do.call(rbind,strsplit(a,"T")))
```

Result:

```
     a                        
[1,] "abcT123"   "abc"   "123"
[2,] "Dsds1Tdf4" "Dsds1" "df4"
```

Look at `?strsplit`.